# Module parse error & cannot read properties of undefined

Tags: javascript, reactjs, web, babeljs, babel-loader

I was making a React file and this problem arrived:
`TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'map')`

```
  35 |                </Select>
  36 |            </FormControl>
  37 | 
> 38 |            <Grid container spacing={3} className={classes.list}>
     | ^  39 |                {places.map((place, i) => (
  40 |                    <Grid item key={i} xs={12}>
  41 |                        <PlaceDetails place={place}/>
```

I found on the web that I could solve this problem by applying an `?.` on `{places.map...}`, then it will be `{places?.map...`. I solved the first problem, but, unfortunately, this happened when I saved the changes:
`
./src/components/List/List.jsx 153:12
Module parse failed: Unexpected token (153:12)
You may need an appropriate loader to handle this file type.
|       columnNumber: 13
|     }

> }, places?.map(function (place, i) {
> |     return /*#**PURE***/React.createElement(Grid, {
> |       item: true,
> `

Does anyone know what I need to do to solve the problem? Did I make the right choice using `?.` or maybe I need to make something different?

I understand that the `?.` can't be recognized in my project (and I don't know why), but I know he can solve my problem. Here's where I find the `?.` solution

Comment: Did you check the existence of the array you are mapping before trying to render it ?

Answer (score 1):

Change

`{places.map`...

to

`{places && places.map`...

so it won't try to display the places when `places` is falsy.